# Converter para lista uma string de uma lista que contem base64?

Tags: python, django, base64

Recebo por meio de uma requisição **json** um `request.POST` que vem como uma lista de string base64.

Consigo converter para string com `str(request.POST['imagem'])` o que resulta algo assim:

> ['eJzFnemyozqwpQXeNdz7/i/bHWXTP7zTXiy+lZKrTkQrwmHQkJNyAoTYfv36dWzHGGPfxhhjPB6P',
>   ...]

Com a biblioteca AST em qualquer outra lista do mesmo tipo  consigo converter para uma lista do *python* com: `ast.literal_eval(list_string)`, porém quando vem com base64 dentro da lista, ele dá erro de sintaxe:

> File "", line 2
>   eJzFnemyozqwpQXeNdz7/i/bHWXTP7zTXiy+lZKrTkQrwmHQkJNyAoTYfv36dWzHGGPfxhhjPB6P
>                      ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Alguma idéia?

Como converter isso para uma lista utilizável do *python*?

Comment: `import base64 
base64.b64decode(coded_string)`.
Tente assim por favor

Answer (score 1):

Se a sua resposta é um json válido você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
import json

lista = json.dumps(request.POST['imagem'])
```

E pronto.